# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 from a terminal

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

How do I upgrade to 14.04 around my existing system with out re-installing?
I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 currently.
I have checked through update manager.
Is there a way to do it through Terminal?

Answer (score 3):

The (discussable) best way to do it is to switch to a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and login.

No enter `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Remember to disable all PPA's before trying to upgrade, else the upgrade may fail and your system may become unusable.

**Have a backup** before. The upgrade can always fail and leave you with a broken system.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple partitions, an upgrade should not touch your data (assuming /home is where you put your data and it was a different partition.) If you have a database, however, it will be in /var which the ugprade process tends to play with quite a bit.